# Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to run the below code:

```
var result = filteredResults.Where(row => applicantSearchRequestModel.Subjects.Where(s => s != null).All(row.SubjectArea.Contains)).ToList();
```

where filteredResults is a List, each element contain a SubjectArea string property

and applicantSearchRequestModel.Subjects is an array to strings.

I'm trying to loop through each filterResults trying to check if the SubjectArea string contains all the elements in the applicantSearchRequestModel.Subjects array.

But I am getting the below error:

> Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.' error

Comment: Try `Where(row => row.SubjectArea != null && // everything else`

Comment: So what you want to do when `SubjectArea` **is** null?

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this?

```
var result = filteredResults.Where(row => 
    applicantSearchRequestModel.Subjects
        .Where(s => s != null)
        .All(subject => row.SubjectArea.Contains(subject)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I still needed the row.SubjectArea != null check that @Aluan Haddad mentioned above

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**